# Fees and delays in getting physical stock

Tags: united-states, stocks, fees, broker

If I buy shares from a certain US stock broker, what are on average the fees and delays to get the physical stock upon request?

If the prices do not have a clear average, which US based broker has the lowest fees for this?

Comment: The part of your question that reads "which ___ has the lowest price for ___" is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

DTC cost are $6 plus certified mailing costs and brokers tack on their own processing fees.  US broker generally have very high fees to transfer and ship stock("T&S").  Even the discount brokers charge upward of $500 for one certificate.  These high fees appear designed to deter investors from requesting certificates.  Some brokers that you pay for advice and where you hold significant assets would probably charge less or my even waive the fee depending of size of assets. Also note that some brokers will not issue physical certificates.  Based on this the an average fee would probably be somewhere around $300 or so.  Most will suggest that processing will take 4-6 weeks but rush requests can be made for additional fees.

I believe DRIP program sponsor/agent such as (Computershare) has a lower T&S fee  compared to most brokers.

Also note that DTC is pushing to move away from issuing Physical Certificates.  http://www.dtcc.com/news/2013/march/12/full_dematerialization.aspx

Lastly note that that some issuers are moving away from issuing physical stock certificates in favor of book only.  Facebook, Apple, Disney are a few notable.  I would expect that trend to continue.